# Determining how much battery life/power is left on your current charge in iOS

Tags: ios, battery

How does one determine how power is remaining on iOS product from code. i.e 50%

Answer (score 1):

you can get current battery level by using -

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];`

from documentation -

> Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100%
>   charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery
>   monitoring is enabled.